# How to stop MySQL replicating users on slave

Tags: mysql

I have set `--replicate-ignore-db=mysql` in MySQL slave, but still it is replicating any users I create on the master.

Is there a way to stop the slave from replicating users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For statement-based replication(the default for mixed binary logging format), `--replicate-ignore-db=foo_db` works only when `foo_db` is explicitly used as in `USE foo_db`. In a `GRANT` or `REVOKE` statement, `USE mysql` is not executed, as can be seen from the binary log.

For row-based replication, if `--replicate-ignore-db=foo_db`, any direct change to a table in `foo_db` would not be replicated to the slave. But MySQL always uses statement-based logging for statements that indirectly change the tables of `mysql` database(`GRANT`, `REVOKE`, `SET PASSWORD`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, `CREATE`), regardless of the value of `binlog_format`.

So, to stop replicating any changes in `mysql` database to slave, you can set `binlog-ignore-db=mysql` in your master's configuration file to stop logging any changes in `mysql` database. You can also temporarily turn off `sql_log_bin` for your session and `CREATE`/`ALTER` the user before turning the variable back on again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use --Replicate_Ignore_table=mysql.user, because while modifying, creating, deleting user it modifies mysql.user table.

Comment: I have ignored the whole mysql database on slave but it still replicates new users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an extra answer as I can't comment Alok's answer yet.

In addition to what [Alok said:](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233187/22336)
watch out that any `replicate-ignore-db`option is useless if you have a `replicate-do-db` option  (see [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rules-db-options.html)).

An alternative is to use `replicate-wild-ignore-table = mysql.%` to ignore all mysql tables (not only users but their grants as well).